# Having trouble with Python Web Scraper

Tags: scrapy

i'm new to scrapping and would love some help or just a push along in the right direction. I've currently tried using scrapy but could not get it working at all. 
What i'm trying to do is get the titles, episode and html 5 video player link's + different qualities (480p, 720p,etc..) from this [page](http://getanime.to/recent). I'm not sure how i'm meant to get the video src's from the iframe elements though.

As mentioned before any help would be very helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have previous experience with Scrapy, but I'm in the middle of a Python Web Scraping project myself. I'm using BeautifulSoup for scraping.

I've written part of the code - this gets all of the titles, episodes, thumbnails, and loads the link to the new page for further processing. If you're having more troubles, leave a message ;)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import request

url = "http://getanime.to/recent"
h = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req = request.Request(url, headers=h)
data = request.urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
# print(soup.prettify()[:1000]) # For testing purposes - should print out the first 1000 characters of the HTML document

links = soup.find_all('a', class_="episode-release")
for link in links:
    # Get required info from this link
    thumbnail = link.find('div', class_="thumbnail")["style"]
    thumbnail = thumbnail[22:len(thumbnail)-3]
    title = link.find('div', class_="title-text").contents[0].strip()
    episode = link.find('div', class_="super-block").span.contents[0]
    href = link["href"]
    # print(thumbnail, title, episode, href) # For testing purposes

    # Load the link to this episode for further processing
    req2 = request.Request(href, headers=h)
    data2 = request.urlopen(req2)
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(data2)

    vid_sources = soup2.find('ul', class_="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu--top video-sources")
    # TODO repeat the above process to find all video sources
```

Edit: the above code is for python3. For clarification.

Comment: Hi @Nietvoordekat, Thanks for the quick rely and for the code above. However for some reason it doesn't seem to be working for me? 
Thanks - Cheese

Comment: Make sure you [have Beautifulsoup installed](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). Also: I believe that the `from urllib import request` part only works when using python3. What version of Python are you using? What errors are you getting?

Comment: Currently there are no clear errors, it just doesn't display anything when run. Previously there was a problem with request not being imported properly since i was using 2.7 but now i'm using 3.6.

Comment: I apologize, I should've been clearer. The code is a push in the right direction - apart from the `print` statements (which are commented out), it doesn't "display" anything. Rather, I assumed you wanted to do something else with the values, like insert them into a database. It also isn't complete, as I didn't write the second part (the video sources and their resolution).

Comment: Try playing with the code a bit, see what you can find and what you can print. If you can't get it to work, get back to me and I'll try to help you out ;)

Comment: Oh wow, silly me, my brain was not working yesterday :P. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: No problem! Good luck ;)

Comment: Hey, sorry to ask more questions, but i've tried to get the data from the iframes but have run into a problem. Currently it can display the iframe, but i can't print anything inside of it. 
`def get_single_item_data(item_url):
    source_code = request.Request(item_url, headers=h)
    d_ = request.urlopen(source_code)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(d_, 'lxml')
    iframexx = soup.find_all('iframe')
    for iframe in iframexx:
        print(iframexx)
        print(iframe.string) `

The `iframexx` displays the `iframe` but the iframe returns "None".

Answer (score 0):

(posting as another answer, since comments remove linebreaks):

Sure, happy to help ;) you're very much on the right track, so keep at it. I am wondering why you're using `find_all('iframe')`, since I couldn't find any examples with multiple `iframe`'s, but it'll work just as well I guess. If you know there's only one, it saves some time to use `soup.find()`.

Using `type(iframexx)` shows me that it points to a list which contains the actual data we want. Then

```
for iframe in iframexx:
    print(type(iframexx))
    ifr = iframexx[0]
    print(ifr)
    print(ifr["data-src"])
```

allowed me to get the data-src.

Comment: Happy to be of assistance ;)